# Strange dash arithmetics

Tags: bash, sh, dash-shell

Having the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env dash
seq -w 10 | while read -r num
do
    echo $num: $((num + 1))
done
```

prints

```
01: 2
02: 3
03: 4
04: 5
05: 6
06: 7
07: 8
sd: 3: sd: Illegal number: 08
```

Can anyone explain what is the problem with above `dash` artihmetic?

note, it is an **dash** (not bash) script.

Tagged it as `bash` too, for more attention from bash-experts too. :)

Comment: somewhat i forgot the octal numbers - it is same for `bash` too... really stupid question - have a bad day today.. ;(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is leading `0` in your `seq` output that makes it **an octal** number and anything above `07` is an invalid octal number.

Note that this script will work fine without error:

```
seq 10 | while read -r num; do echo "$num: $((num + 1))"; done
```